# How do I install Star Wars Battlefront 1?

Tags: software-installation, wine

I can Install most windows games but I can't install Star Wars Battlefront on my Ubuntu 12.10 laptop computer.

Answer (score 1):

Star Wars Battlefront 1 can sometimes work on `wine`, but often there are problems or glitches with the graphics, so it depends on your particular setup and version of `wine` as to **if** or how well it will run. It may well be available on Steam in the near future, but that is just surmise.

Nevertheless, so we can get an answer for this question, here's how I installed it on Ubuntu 12.04, which was largely a similar process to that very briefly mentioned on the [information page at WineHQ](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4785&iTestingId=7630).

I usually recommend using a fresh WINEPREFIX for every new application installed with `wine`, as that very often eliminates problems that using the default `~/.wine` folder with everything can cause.

**Note:** `Playonlinux` can be used to install it as well, but here's how I did it manually. If you don't fancy all the barrage of terminal commands below, you can use `playonlinux` to install, but see my important note further below about `securom` errors.

1) Locate your legal copy of the game and its 3 cds (you will need the CD key as well) and place the first disk in the drive and make sure it mounts correctly.

2) Create your new WINEPREFIX with:

```
WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.battlefront1 winecfg
```

This will make the wine configuration window come up, and before you dismiss it, check the drive letter that the battlefront CD has been symlinked to (usually D:).

2) Start the install (assuming the `wine` drive is D:):

```
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.battlefront1 wine "D:/GameData/setup.exe"
```

(You can of course `export` the WINEPREFIX environmental variable to your environment, but for clarity I will specify it each time here with `env`.)

3) Enter the CD key and let the installer begin. When you swap disks, wait for the next disk to mount **before** you click continue. When you get the confirmation screen that it has installed, do **not** launch it yet.

4) Download the official Lucasarts patch and install it:

```
cd 
wget "ftp://ftp.lucasarts.com/patches/pc/Battlefront1_2_Eng.exe"
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.battlefront1 wine "Z:/home/mike/Battlefront1_2_Eng.exe"
```

The drive letter referring to the local filesystem should be `Z:` and the command assumes the file is in your home folder.

5) Now, if you try to run the program it will hang or give you an error about securom, as `wine` doesn't support securom. The only way to get around this is to use a no-cd 'patched' executable that supports version 1.2 English (or your language).

**Disclaimer:** For legal reasons, I cannot provide any download links for patched executables.

6) After all that is sorted out you may want to tweak some graphic settings with `winetricks`:

```
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.battlefront1 winetricks
```

It is tricky to specify what settings to alter, but often those to do with pixel shading and multisampling need to be off, but you may need to tweak other ones and experiment a little.

7) Finally, run the game with:

```
env WINEPREFIX=$HOME/.battlefront1 wine "C:/Program Files/LucasArts/Star Wars Battlefront/GameData/Battlefront.exe"
```

You must always run it from the Gamedata folder and never with the launcher.

It is difficult to say how well it will run on other systems, and often there are regressions in `wine` so it may be difficult to run at all, so keep an eye on the [WineHQ page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=4785&iTestingId=7630). This guide might be useful for you for this game, or to use as a model for installing other games as well using `wine`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @user76204's comment and perhaps a more simple or elegant solution, if you own the games on Steam or are not opposed to purchasing them again on Steam both work great with the Steam compatibility layer [Proton](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Proton).

According to [ProtonDB](https://www.protondb.com/) both the classic [Battlefront 1](https://www.protondb.com/app/1058020) and [Battlefront 2](https://www.protondb.com/app/6060) work very well on Proton. I have found that using Proton in addition to or as a replacement for WINE is a remarkably simple solution for getting non-GNU/Linux games to run.

[Here](https://www.howtogeek.com/738967/how-to-use-steams-proton-to-play-windows-games-on-linux/) is a fairly straightforward explanation on how to run Steam games with Proton.

To do so:

- Right click on the game on the Steam menu.
- Select the "Properties" option.
- Then select the "Compatibility" option on the left-hand side.
- Then select the "Force the use of a specific Steam Play compatibility tool."
- Install the game.